# About the use of tasklet_hrtimer_init in hardware interrupt callback function

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, irq

Comment of function `tasklet_hrtimer_init`：

> Init a tasklet/hrtimer combo for softirq callbacks

There are few routines used in kernel about `tasklet_hrtimer_init`.

Can `tasklet_hrtimer_init`  be used in the callback function of hardware interrupt?

Comment: Of course not.  It starts a tasklet, including setting up mempools and using spinlocks.  Why would you do that in an interrupt routine?  An interrupt routine should do the minimum needed to service the interrupt.

Comment: Will mempools  and spinlocks affect  tasklet_hrtimer_init?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I would highly recommend doing the initialization before setting up the IRQ handler. In the IRQ handler routine, you could start or restart an already initialized hrtimer, or try to cancel a started hrtimer.